# how create my own directive for lowercase

Tags: angular

I want to create my own directive, but it does not work:

**input-format.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef,Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appInputFormat]'
}) 
export class InputFormatDirective {
  @Input('format') format;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('blur') onBlur(){
    let value:string = this.el.nativeElement.value;

    if(this.format=="lowercase"){
      this.el.nativeElement.value = value.toUpperCase();
    }else{
      this.el.nativeElement.value = value.toLowerCase();
    }

  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
[<input type="text" appInputFormat \['format'\]="'lowercase'" >][1]
```

Comment: What is your **actual** HTML code? What are you doing, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? Not that your logic is inverted: lowercase converts to uppercase. Other than that, with the correct HTML, your code works fine. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cktwgy

Comment: its work thx bro

Answer (score 0):

I think the condition is incorrect.

```
if(this.format == "lowercase") {
    this.el.nativeElement.value = value.toLowerCase();
} else {
    this.el.nativeElement.value = value.toUpperCase();
}
```